# akka-http client singleRequest round-robin on a list of possible hosts

Tags: scala, client, akka-http, round-robin

I am sending requests to another service using akka-http client's `Http().singleRequest(uri = Uri(hostUri))`

I have a list of the cluster's hosts - `hosts: List[String]`. I would like to use some kind of round-robin to send the request to either one of them while the others will be used as backup in case the request fails.

Answer (score 0):

From the question it seems that you perfectly understand what you need to implement. What exactly is challenging you? How to do random / round robin or how to make another request in case of failure? I believe not the first one, since people who brave enough to start using akka-http know how to do randomisation. For the second part I recommend to take a look on retriable Future from dispatch library:

https://www.bimeanalytics.com/engineering-blog/retrying-http-request-in-scala/

Comment: I meant making another request in case of failure *but* with a different url

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought the implementation would be long and that there are tools I miss that will make it simpler.
Eventually I figured out it *is* simple to implement recursively

```
  def autorecoveredRequest(
    hosts: List[String],
    hostToRequest: (String) => HttpRequest)(
    implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[HttpResponse] =
    Random.shuffle(hosts) match {
      case host :: rest =>
        Http().singleRequest(hostToRequest(host)).recoverWith {
          case e =>
            log.warn(s"Request to host ${host} failed")
            autorecoveredRequest(rest, hostToRequest)
        }
      case Nil =>
        log.error("No more hosts to recover request")
        Future.failed(new Exception("No more hosts to recover request"))
    }
```

The only thing that might be missing here is a per host request retry which in my case was not the issue